# Remove previous directories before cloning in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: command-line, bash, find, gitlab

I am using Gitlab Runner for deploy new website version into server.
Original scenario of deploying is to shallow clone to new directory with current date time string like "2019-10-27-17-43-05".
then system will create new symlink from main app directory to this new folder. after running compiling and other jobs.
so after some days we have many file and folders that not used and filling up hard disk.

```
releases/
releases/2019-10-29-10-49-31
releases/2019-10-29-01-27-44
releases/2019-10-29-14-51-59
releases/2019-10-27-17-43-05
releases/2019-10-28-00-20-16
releases/2019-10-29-14-31-18
releases/2019-10-28-19-00-41
releases/2019-10-29-01-11-43
releases/2019-10-29-14-22-41
releases/2019-10-28-00-03-52
releases/2019-10-27-17-15-24
releases/2019-10-28-00-17-26
releases/2019-10-29-01-20-44
releases/2019-10-27-23-12-52
releases/2019-10-29-10-47-17
releases/2019-10-29-14-24-11
```

symlinks are here:

```
ubuntu@saatchi:/usr/local/lsws/app$ ll
total 44
drwxrwxr-x+  4 nobody        gitlab-runner 4096 Oct 29 14:56 ./
drwxrwxr-x+  4 nobody        gitlab-runner 4096 Oct 27 17:11 ../
-rw-rwxr--+  1 nobody        root           749 Oct 27 17:05 .env*
-rw-rwxr--+  1 nobody        gitlab-runner   23 Oct 24 17:48 .gitignore*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner   62 Oct 29 14:56 current -> /usr/local/lsws/app/releases/2019-10-29-14-51-59/
drwxrwxr-x+ 20 nobody        gitlab-runner 4096 Oct 29 14:51 releases/
drwxrwxr-x+  6 nobody        gitlab-runner 4096 Oct 24 17:48 storage/
```

Please recommend best practices to remove this old directories.
My own opinion is to remove all old directories exclude 2 recent. after successful cloning, with "find" command. if this is good please tell me full command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web to find a solution. At last i found that:
with this code you can keep 5 latest versions.

```
ls -1t | tail -n +5 | xargs rm -rf
```